# Can we convert a live video stream into a byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-streaming, live-streaming

I'm using C#.NET I'm getting a live video stream from a url(rtsp://streamurl). Now I want to know if we can convert this live stream into a byte array so that I can use NReco.VideoConverter component to encode this Stream using .h264 and then stream it via a server.

I'm currently gathering details and studying basics on NReco.VideoEncoder. It has [a method to convert a live video stream](http://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.VideoConverter/html/M_NReco_VideoConverter_FFMpegConverter_ConvertLiveMedia_1.htm), but for the input file, it requires System.IO.Stream instead of a URL path. That's why I'm asking this question. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, but you need to know what data (structure) needs to be put into the byte stream.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with NReco.VideoEncoder, so this is just a guess:

When looking at your link to the interface you'll see:

```
public ConvertLiveMediaTask ConvertLiveMedia(
    Stream inputStream,
    string inputFormat,
    string outputFile,
    string outputFormat,
    ConvertSettings settings
)
```

Stream is very flexible (first input param), so you should be able to use anything from file as well as web... so you should be able to do it this way (haven't compiled this code):

```
  // convert url to stream
  WebRequest request=WebRequest.Create(url); // your rtsc url?
  request.Timeout=30*60*1000;
  request.UseDefaultCredentials=true;
  request.Proxy.Credentials=request.Credentials;
  WebResponse response=(WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
  {
      var converter = new FFMpegConverter(); // init converter
      converter.ConvertLiveMedia(stream, // put your stream here
                                 "???", // problem here... no rtsc support in Formats enum found, so you might need to know the video format 
                                 "C:\whateverpath\whatever.hevc", // extension?
                                 Format.h265);

  }
```

I don't see how rtsc is supported here and you might need to now what kind of video encoding is packed into rtsc first, otherwise the converter doesn't understand the input (at least when using this interface you mentioned).
And that's what I meant in my comment: You need to know the data structure of the (byte) stream to know how to interpret the bits or you have to make a guess.

Their website states the feature:

- Live video stream transcoding from C# Stream (or Webcam, RTSP URL, file) to C# 
  Stream (or streaming server URL, file)